# Add id attribute to h1 element of wordpress post

Tags: html, wordpress, filter

The default rendering of the `h1` element of a wordpress post looks like this:

```
<h1 class="entry-title"> XYZ </h1>
```

I would like to add the `id` attribute to the `h1` element with the value of the post's title. The result should look as follows

```
<h1 id="XYZ" class="entry-title"> XYZ </h1>
```

I have already looked through many posts here, but couldn't find an answer to my question. Shouldn't there be a simple filter for `functions.php` to override the rendering of the `h1` element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on where you are pulling the single post template, you can modify the output like this:

```
<h1 id="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>" class="entry-title"> XYZ </h1>
```

Look at the `single.php` file and see where you are loading the template for displaying single posts. The above should run inside the WordPress loop.

Also `get_the_title()` pulls the title without formating, what you are looking for is probably the post slug.